# Reset a crontab file in centos?

Tags: centos, cron

I have a crontab file that is no longer allowing me to edit it. When executing

```
/usr/bin/crontab -e
```

I get the following output

```
/usr/bin/crontab: line 8: 15: command not found
/usr/bin/crontab: line 9: 40: command not found
/usr/bin/crontab: line 10: 45: command not found
/usr/bin/crontab: line 11: 00: command not found
/usr/bin/crontab: line 12: 00: command not found
/usr/bin/crontab: line 13: 00: command not found
/usr/bin/crontab: line 14: 45: command not found
/usr/bin/crontab: line 15: 50: command not found
```

Is there a way for me to reset this file to a default version. All commands on the crontab fail with the same error so I not able to use

> /usr/bin/crontab -r

to remove it. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: That looks suspiciously like your `/usr/bin/crontab` has been replaced with an actual crontab file that the system attempts to interpret as a shell script of sorts...

Comment: That could very well be true. I tried `emacs /usr/bin/crontab` and deleted all lines (which looked like my crontab file), however after that when I used the crontab commands above nothing happens.

Comment: You'll probably have to reinstall the package that owns `/usr/bin/crontab`, or restore from a backup or something. That's generally a binary program file, and it's been destroyed at this point...